# How do I get the position of a node made from the DrawNode function?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have drawn a circle using the DrawNode function.
Then I am checking to see if the user is clicking the circle or not

Here I am creating the circle

```
DrawNode *drawnode = DrawNode::create();
drawnode->drawDot(ccp(10, Director::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize().height / 5 ), 10, Color4F(2, 99, 2, 2));
drawnode->setPosition(Point(winSize.width / 2.1 + origin.x, winSize.height / 5 + origin.y));
this->addChild(drawnode);
```

Here is where I am checking to if the user is clicking the Circle

```
  if(Level::drawnode->getPosition() == touch->getLocation()) {  CCLOG("Circle has been clicked"); } else {  CCLOG("Circle has not been clicked"); }
```

The problem is this if statement keeps going to the else statement.

How do I get the circles position on the screen so that when the circle is clicked correctly

Answer (score 0):

A `DrawNode` doesn't provide such functionality. It's basically a simple node which draws shapes without no knowledge about the contained shapes. It's just a graphical node which enqueues all the draw primitives.

To do what you need to do you need to keep your logic informations somewhere, eg:

```
struct Circle
{
  Position position;
  float radius;

  bool isInside(const Position& location) {
    // return distance beween location and position < radius
  }
}

std::vector<Circle> circles;

// do it the when circles vector changes
void rebuildDrawNode()
{
  drawNode.clear();
  for (const Circle& circle : circles) {
    drawNode->drawDot(...)
}

void checkIfTouches(const Position& position) {
  for (const Circle& circle : circles) {
    if (circle.isInside(position)) {
      // do what you need
    }
  }
}
```

As a side node, never use `operator==` to compare `Position`, always test if difference between coordinates is lesser than a specified amount.